# How do I get a list of changed files in svn?

Tags: svn, diff

I just want a list of files that are different between my working directory and the repository. `summary` only seems to report differences between repositories.

Comment: As others have said you need to run svn status. Also check out this link for a quick check on what each status means. http://knaddison.com/technology/svn-status-code-cheat-sheet

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Run `svn status`.  It will distinguish between modified, deleted, added, etc.  `svn help status` has a bunch of information for you.

Comment: Not helpful or answering the question, shouldn't be the accepted answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26358015/2279059 instead.

Comment: OK, it looks like the title of the question does not agree with the content of the question. Should be edited.

Comment: Continue this command in Windows with a pipe findstr and you get the answer to the original question:  `svn status | findstr "^M"`

Comment: `svn status -q` is the more direct way to do `svn status | findstr "^M"` (or `svn status | grep ^M`, as I had grown accustomed to do)

Answer (score 42):

Try

```
svn diff --summarize -r startRevision:endRevision URL.
```

Comment: The answer to _this_ question is `svn status`, but you answered _my_ question, so I still upvoted. `URL` is optional btw.

Comment: save my time ,great answer

Answer (score 13):

`svn status` is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

**svn diff | grep Index:**

It worked with my revision. If command does not work for you, run the following command on a directory with small number of changes:

**svn diff > out.txt**

Open the **out.txt**. You will notice that every line that contains needed file name starts with the same string (In my case, it was "**Index:**"), grep for it and you will get what you want.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to SVN Diff between 2 branches

```
svn diff --summarize ^/branches/branch-1.15 ^/branches/branch-1.16
```

Answer (score 0):

Python solution:

```
import subprocess    

ps = subprocess.Popen(('svn status'), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = subprocess.check_output(('findstr "^M"'), stdin=ps.stdout).decode("utf-8")
ps.wait()


print(output)
```