# SVN: how to list all new files added after a tag is created?

Tags: svn

SVN: how to list all new files added after a tag is created? e.g.

A tag "2.0" is created at revision 1234.
Need to list all new files added in trunk after the tag 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of changed files, use `svn diff --summarize` as explained in  [How do I get a list of changed files in svn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798822/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-changed-files-in-svn)

To get only the files that were added, you can filter through grep for an 'A' in the first column like this:

```bash
svn diff --summarize ^/tags/2.0 ^/trunk | grep "^A"
```

BTW, a tag is just another revision in Subversion and not different from a branch or trunk. Creating a tag at 1234 will create a new revision 1235. Just a technical detail and not relevant to this question at all but I thought I'd point it out.

Finally, the obligatory reference to the [Red Bean Book on diff](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html).

Comment: Files (e.g. foo.txt) added in trunk after tag 2.0: shown as added  
 ^/tags/2.0/foo.txt.

Comment: Sorry for my late reaction - I was on vacation. I don't understand your comment. Did I answer your question? If not, what's missing?

Comment: @eastwater not sure if you were notified that I reacted to your comment. Same question as above.